# How to find out where the Python include directory is?

Tags: python

I know that after installing Python via Homebrew my include directory is here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
```

Is there a way I can make Python tell me where its include/lib directories are? Something along the lines of:

```
python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)"
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There must be an easier way to do this from Python, I thought, and there is, in the standard library of course. Use `get_paths` from [`sysconfig`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sysconfig.html) :

```
from sysconfig import get_paths
from pprint import pprint

info = get_paths()  # a dictionary of key-paths

# pretty print it for now
pprint(info)
{'data': '/usr/local',
 'include': '/usr/local/include/python2.7',
 'platinclude': '/usr/local/include/python2.7',
 'platlib': '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 'platstdlib': '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 'purelib': '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 'scripts': '/usr/local/bin',
 'stdlib': '/usr/lib/python2.7'}
```

You could also use the `-m` switch with `sysconfig` to get the full output of all configuration values.

This should be OS/Python version agnostic, use it anywhere. :-)

Comment: When I do this, it shows `'include': '/usr/include/python3.7m'`, but when I try to `cd` to that directory, it says "No such file or directory"

Comment: This is clutch! I was losing my mind looking for this.
sysconfig rules!

Answer (score 17):

On my PC, the command is `python-config --includes`. Make sure you use the `python-config` that homebrew installed, not the default one.

Comment: It works! Is there an analog for finding Python's lib?

Comment: Try `python-config --help` or `python-config --libs`.

Comment: Some Python distributions (such as Anaconda) do not come with `python-config`. If `python-config` is used to determine include path name, then it may be pointing to the include path of the python came with your OS.

Answer (score 15):

My one-line solution is

```
python -c "from sysconfig import get_paths as gp; print(gp()['include'])"
```

If you would like to embed the code within a Unix shell (such as bash), you have to use escaped double quotations.

```
python -c "from sysconfig import get_paths as gp; print(gp()[\"include\"])"
```