# How to create C-extension/embed Python with MinGW-w64 on Windows

Tags: python, cython, mingw-w64

Is it possible (and how) to use MinGW-w64 for building of C-extensions for Python or embeding Python on Windows?

Let's take as example the following cython-extension `foo.pyx`:

```py
print("foo loaded")
```

from which the C-code can be generated either via `cython -3 foo.pyx` or `cython -3 --embed foo.pyx` if interpreter should be embedded.

Answer (score 3):

While `mingw-w64`-compiler is not really supported (the only supported windows compiler is [MSVC](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Which_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_compiler_to_use_with_a_specific_Python_version_.3F)), it can be used to create C-extensions or to embed Python. There are however no guarantee, this won't break in the future versions.

`distutils` does not support `mingw-w64`, so there is no gain in setting up a setup.py-file - the steps must be performed manually.

First we need some information usually provided by `distutils`:

- *Headers:* We need the path to the Python includes. For a way to find them see this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35071192/5769463).
- *DLL:*  mingw-w64's linker works differently than MSVC's: python-dll and **not** python-lib is needed. So we need the path to the `pythonXY.dll` which is usually next the the `python.exe`.

Once the C-code is created/generated, the extension can be build via

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared foo.c -DMS_WIN64 -O2 <other_options> -I <path_to_python_include> -L <path_to_python_dll> -lpython37 -o foo.pyd
```

The important details are:

- it is probably Ok to use only use `-O2` for optimization and leave `<other_options>` empty-
- It is important to define `MS_WIN64`-macro (e.g. via `-DMS_WIN64`). In order to build for x64 on windows it must be set, but it works out of the box only [for MSVC](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4fe098d1ee4f4056ac65cae55f5ffdd439dede0/PC/pyconfig.h#L116-L118) (defining `_WIN64` could have slightly different outcomes):

```
#ifdef _WIN64
#define MS_WIN64
#endif
```

if it is not done, at least for files generated by Cython the following error message will be generated by the compiler:

```
 error: enumerator value for ‘__pyx_check_sizeof_voidp’ is not an integer constant
  201 |     enum { __pyx_check_sizeof_voidp = 1 / (int)(SIZEOF_VOID_P == sizeof(void*)) };
```

- `pyd` is just a dll in disguise, thus we need the `-shared` option, which means a dynamic library (i.e. shared-object in Linux-world) will be created.
- It is important, that the python-library (`pythonXY`) should be the dll itself and not the `lib` (see this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43347809/5769463)). Thua we use the path to `pythonXY.dll` (in my case python37) and not `pythonXY.lib`, as it would be the case for MSVC.

One probably should add the proper suffix to the resulting pyd-file, I use the old convention for simplicity here.

---

**Embeded Python:**

In this case an executable should be build (e.g. the C-file is generated by Cython with `--embed` option: `cython -3 --embed foo.pyx`) and thus the command line looks as follows:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc foo.c -DMS_WIN64 -O2 <other_options> -I <path_to_python_include> -L <path_to_python_dll> -lpython37 -o foo.exe -municode
```

There are two important differences:

- `-shared` should no longer be used, as the result is no longer a dynamic library (that is what *.pyd-file is after all) but an executable.
- `-municode` is needed, because for Windows, Cython defines `int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)` instead of `int main(int argc, char** argv)`. Without this option, an error message like

```
/build/mingw-w64-_1w3Xm/mingw-w64-4.0.4/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to 'WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

would appear (see this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58324230/5769463) for more information).

**Note:** for the resulting executable to run, a whole python-distribution (and not only the dll) is needed (see also this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62390978/5769463)), otherwise the resulting executable will abort with error (either the python dll wasn't found or the python installation or the site packages - depending on the configuration of the machine on which the exe has to run).

---

`mingw-w64` can also be used on Linux for cross-compilation for Windows, see this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70474888/5769463).