# Exe file compiled from c is not executable

Tags: python, c, exe, cython

I'm trying to run a .exe file compiled from c, but got results 'this app can't open in this pc and I don't understand why. The c code is made from python file using cython, and I'm sure the python code works. The python code is:

```
import socket
import os
import sys
import struct


def socket_service():
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        # IP address for pc
        s.bind(('', 8088))
        s.listen(7)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)
        sys.exit(1)

    print("Connection open, waiting for picture...")

    while True:
        sock, addr = s.accept()
        deal_data(sock, addr)

    s.close()

def deal_data(sock, addr):
    print("Connection done {0}".format(addr))

    while True:
        fileinfo_size = struct.calcsize('128sl')
        buf = sock.recv(fileinfo_size)
        if buf:
            filename, filesize = struct.unpack('128sl', buf)
            fn = filename.decode().strip('\x00')
            #PC saved pic address
            #new_filename = os.path.join('C:/Users/user/Desktop', fn)
            new_filename = os.path.join('C:/Users/lguo8', fn)

            recvd_size = 0
            fp = open(new_filename, 'wb')

            while not recvd_size == filesize:
                if filesize - recvd_size > 1024:
                    data = sock.recv(1024)
                    recvd_size += len(data)
                else:
                    data = sock.recv(1024)
                    recvd_size = filesize
                fp.write(data)
            fp.close()
        sock.close()
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket_service()
```

And I use cython to convert python to c by:

```
python translate.py build_ext --inplace -DMS_WIN64
```

where the translate.py is

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize('try_pi_socket_10.py'))
```

After I got try_pi_socket_10.c, I enter command:

```
gcc -DMS_WIN64 try_pi_socket_10.c -o output -IC:/Users/lguo8/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/include -LC:/Users/lguo8/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/libs  -lpython39 -municode -shared
```

in order to get execute file.
However, I was expected to get a file 'output' without any extension. But actually the file is 'output.exe', and when I tried to run it in cmd, I got result 'this app can't open in this pc, permission denied'.
Can anyone please help me to run this execute file please? Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70654723/5769463. You need to drop shared and possible to update the library path.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I read your post and find you met the same problems there. But I can't drop -shared otherwise there's a error. And I've updated the library path to python39.dll, but seems still not working. It stills gives me a .exe file. Can I ask the way you run the .exe file please?

Comment: You probably need to call Cython with `embed`. You _must_ drop shared because it is asking for a shared library and not an executable