# Is there a viable way to compile cython extensions on Windows without admin privileges to install VS community?

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, clang, cython, admin

I have a laptop for which I lack admin privileges.

I'm developing a project using cython and I need to find a way to compile it there. I should mention in case it's useful to someone, that by using [pure python mode](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html) my code runs 100% correctly as interpreted python. But I need to test the compiled code when I'm working at this laptop too.

I've tried downloading the whole layout of VS 2022 community with the --layout option, but once everything is downloaded (all of 40 gigabytes) the executables vs_setup.exe and vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe run and close without any output, not even from the command line and with option.

I tried putting the layout in a different drive using `SUBST`, to try to [approximate the suggestion at the end of this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/559499/install-application-without-admin-account.html), to no avail.

I have installed LLVM with no admin rights, hoping to compile things manually, as setuptools does not support LLVM out of the box. But then cythonize is asking for `vcvarsall.bat` all the same, and I have my doubts whether it will be enough with the python.dlls to compile and link my extension types.

Does anyone know then of any kind of viable alternative for compiling cython in a windows PC with no admin rights?

Thanks!

Comment: People have got mingw64 to work (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70654723/4657412) but it's definitely not the recommended way of doing things. I don't know if that requires admin rights though

Comment: Thanks. I may end up having to try that. If it works I will post it here.