# Install Cython for Anaconda

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, anaconda, cython

This might have been discussed before.
I am trying to use Cython from Anaconda. I know that a C-compiler is needed and that the compiler from Visual Studio should be preferred. But for different reasons, I wish to not use the Visual Studio compiler.

Has anyone tried and succeeded with GCC compiler?
I am aware there is a warning in the documentation against that particular compiler but is it justified?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

I tried to run cython in anaconda but realized that no C - compiler was installed on my machine.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The [installation instructions](https://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/quickstart/install.html) looks like a good place to start.  What operating system *are* you on?

Comment: A good set of instructions are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70654722/how-to-create-c-extension-embed-python-with-mingw-w64-on-windows.

Comment: The Conda builds of Cython for **win-64** on typical channels (`anaconda`, `conda-forge`) all directly depend on `vc`. While you can still use Conda to manage the Python in the environment, you will need to seek elsewhere to source Cython, etc..