# Cython Embedding Python in a C program - Cant Link to embed.o

Tags: python-3.x, cython

Hi I am new to embedding source code from python into C.
I have a basic program that creates a cython module called "introduction."
The "introduction" module holds one function called "introduction."

```
cdef char* introduction(char* name, char* lastName):
    return "Hello, {} {}!".format(name, lastName).encode("utf-8")
```

We then call it into this program:

```
/**
File            :   embed.c
Project         :   None
Programmer      :   Braiden Gole
First version   :   2023-04-22
Description     :   This is my first embeded python program.

NOTE: Where Python is located.
NOTE: C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include
NOTE: "C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs\python311.lib"
NOTE: "C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.dll"

COMPILE:
gcc -c embed.c -o embed.o -IC:/Users/<my_username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/include
LINK:
gcc -o embed embed.o -IC:/Users/<my_username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/include -LC:/Users/<my_username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/libs -lpython311
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    // Initialize the python interpreter.
    Py_Initialize();

    // Import the CPython module.
    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("introduction");
    if (!pModule)
    {
        printf("%s", "Failed to imprt python module.");
        return 1;
    }

    PyObject* pFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "introduction");

    if (!pFunction || !PyCallable_Check(pFunction))
    {
        printf("%s", "Failed to get python function.");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a tuple and set the arguments of the function.
    PyObject* pArguments = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArguments, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("Braiden"));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArguments, 1, PyUnicode_FromString("Gole"));

    PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunction, pArguments);
    Py_DECREF(pArguments);

    if (!pResult)
    {
        printf("%s", "Failed to call python function.");
        return 1;
    }

    char* introduction = PyBytes_AsString(pResult);
    printf("%s", introduction);
    Py_DECREF(pResult);

    // Clean up resources.
    Py_DECREF(pFunction);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention to the paths show in the code comments as well as the files that those paths end with. Those are the path values I get from my system so I know those directories and files exist.

I can compile the `embed.c` but I cant link the object file `embed.o`.

Could you please help me with this.

Things to note:

- Python is installed to PATH
- Have installed pythons debugging symbols
- Have installed pythons debug binaries.
- I just upgraded to Python 3.11.3
- I have tried to link against my old Python installation Python 3.10 and still nothing.

Here is what I get when I try to link the file:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_ImportModule'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCallable_Check'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_FromString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_FromString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_CallObject'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyBytes_AsString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: embed.o:embed.c:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: try to reorder linker command, move `embed.o` after `-lpython311`

Comment: Thanks for writing in. But unfortunately it still does not work.

Comment: The L-path should include the path to DLL and not LIBS, when compiling with mingw. For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70654722/5769463